# How to Grab stdClass Object Result

Tags: php

can i ask ? . I have class cURL POST into a website ( API Integration ) , and if i post with class. The result is (i use print_r) :

```
stdClass Object
(
 [order] => 200029
)
1
```

How to grab [order] value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$yourVar->order;
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it still failed #sorryformybadenglish